# How can I open images that save in internal storage (cache folder in Android/data/%package%/cache) in android gallery

Tags: android, caching, android-image, android-gallery, android-file

After image was download, I save it in an internal storage at

Android/data/%packagename%/cache directory. below is a code.

```
private class SaveImageToStorage extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    String picName;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    public SaveImageToStorage(String name, Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        this.picName = name;
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if(bitmap != null && !picName.isEmpty()) {
            File file = new File(feedImagesCacheDir.getPath(), extractImageNameFromUrl(picName));
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 80, fos);
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And after all of this I just want to open the image in android gallery.

I try below code and it doesn't work.It show me Toast "can't find the image".

So I've tried remove "file://", then it open gallery with nothing but something like broken image icon.

```
private void openImageInGallery(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://"+getFeedImagesCacheDir().getPath() + "/" + imgName+".webp"), "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I think that maybe I save it in cache folder, so its became private with only access to my app.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.Sorry for my bad ENG.

Answer (score 1):

Cache Image are not view directly because is save like encrypted format so first you download that image and save into SD card. use below code.

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
String wallpaperFilePath=Android/data/%packagename%/cache/imagename;
File cacheDir = GlobalClass.instance().getCacheFolder(this);
File cacheFile = new File(cacheDir, wallpaperFilePath);
InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(cacheFile);
BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = scale;
bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
Bitmap wallpaperBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream, null, bitmapOptions);


File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
myDir.mkdirs();
Random generator = new Random();
int n = 10000;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
File file = new File (myDir, fname);
if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
       wallpaperBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
       out.flush();
       out.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and add this in manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

By using this line you can able to see saved images in the gallery view.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(
Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
        Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download images into DCIM (your gallery folder in sdCard).
Then use below to open gallery:

```
public static final int RESULT_GALLERY = 0;
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent , RESULT_GALLERY );
```

If you want to get result URI or do anything else use this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case QuestionEntryView.RESULT_GALLERY :
        if (null != data) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
            //Do whatever that you desire here. or leave this blank

        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope this help!